# Rotated text producing inconsistent results

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

I'm trying to display rotated text whereby its always absolute positioned to the bottom of its parent. The parent is 100% height of the browser window and I'd like the text to appear 50px from the bottom for all browser/screen sizes.

Here's my code:

```css
html,body,.carousel,.carousel a.item { height: 100%; }
.carousel a.item {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.rotate {
  zoom: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.carousel a.item h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
}
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>This is really short</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Short but also longer but not to long</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

I have a fiddle setup of my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/77xzfsfa/ and here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak the transform-origin and the positioning of the `.rotate` element like this :

```css
html,body,.carousel,.carousel a.item { height: 100%; }
.carousel a.item {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.rotate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.carousel a.item h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate"><h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate"><h1>This is really short</h1></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate"><h1>Short but also longer but not to long</h1></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate"><h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1></div>
  </a>

</div>
```

*Note that I removed all the vendor prefixes in the snippet for answer brievity and removed unecessary CSS.*

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: @egr103 glad to help, I just edited the answer and removed unecessary CSS

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to absolutely position the content of the rotated element.

Just adjust the transforms and transform origin.

```
.rotate{
    zoom: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  transform:translate(100%,0%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
}


.carousel a.item h1 {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel a.item {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel a.item {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.rotate {
  zoom: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  transform: translate(100%, 0%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.carousel a.item h1 {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>This is really short</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97800&w=300&h=800');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Short but also longer but not to long</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item bg-image" style="background-image: url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg');">
    <div class="rotate">
      <h1>Some really long title thats quite long. Did I say it was long?</h1>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do put rotate: -90px

the real bottom is the left

the real right is the bottom

then we can say:

```
 bottom -> right
 right -> top
 top -> left
 left -> bottom
```

but when you put here

```
 left: 0px;
```

it does not really 0px;

because on calculate from the center of div in horizontal position

---

for you code it will be correctly

like this

```
.carousel a.item h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute; bottom:10px; left: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. I think you're trying something I did, which would only work for certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, simply put the `<br>` in the code:

`<div class="rotate">
  <h1>Short but also longer but not to long</h1>
  <br> 
</div>`