# CSS rotated text for responsive layouts

Tags: html, css, rotation

I am using the answer taken from a question I posted a while back: [Rotated text producing inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746173/rotated-text-producing-inconsistent-results) but I need the text displayed differently. I need the first letter of the word at the top with the rotated text anchored to the bottom right as per the below screenshot. Currently the code I have starts the word at the bottom. The solution must work within a fluid/responsive layout.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wy0qq027/

**What I want to achieve**

[image: What I want to achieve]

**CSS:**

```
html,body,.carousel,.carousel a.item { height: 100%; }
.carousel a.item {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.rotate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.carousel a.item h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: change font-size with media query

Comment: @LaljiTadhani How will that help? Its the rotation of the text thats the issue not the size of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text needs to have a positive rotation of 90 degrees to get your desired effect, then attach the div to the right side instead of left

```
.rotate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 100px; /* offset from right */
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[**working jsfiddle fork**](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8frz0tx5/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!